# How to check a value is there or not in a column of a data table?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I've the following DataTable -> dtFinance

```
ID Account Name Quarter FY   Income_Percent  
1  ABC     Ram  Q1      2011  50  
2  XYZ     Hari Q4      2011  35  
3  ABC     Rohit Q3     2011  40  
4  ABC     Ram  Q2      2011  25  
5  XYZ     Hari Q3      2011  60
```

In the above data, I want to check whether Q3 exists in the above DataTable. If exists then i want to get  Income_Percent of the that quarter and the name of the person

How to write a query with LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = (
  from myRow in _db.dtFinance
  where myRow.Quarter == "Q3"
  select new { myRow.Name, myRow.Income_Percent }
);
```

To determine if there are any matches, you use:

```
if (query.Any()) ...
```

To get the Name and Income_Percent of the first item, you can do:

```
var firstRow = query.First();
string name = firstRow.Name;
int incomePercent = firstRow.Income_Percent;
...
```

To do both with only 1 db call, you can do:

```
var firstRow = query.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstRow != null) {
    string name = firstRow.Name;
    int incomePercent = firstRow.Income_Percent;
    ...
}
```

For more information, I'd recommend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740/what-are-some-good-linq-resources
Also, I love [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), and you might find it interesting. You can test these code snippets easily, and can experiment with the LINQ language and your database.

Comment: Suppose if Q3 is not available in the above said table then how to handle the validation first then if validation passes then to get the result. How??

Comment: It's a DataTable. Please help me with proper datatype also. since here Quarter is in 'string' type and Income_Percent is in 'int' datatype. Help me with datatable.AsEnumerable

Comment: If it doesn't exist then what is the validation ?

Answer (score 1):

@Scott Ripley's answer is what you want. I simply wanted to throw out another linq example using method syntax. Most examples you see are query syntax, but I usually prefer method syntax for simple scenarios.

```
var row = _db.dtFinance.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Quarter == "Q3");
if (row != null)
{
    var name = row.Name;
    var incomePercent = row.Income_Percent;
    ...
}
```

I also highly recommend [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) - awesome piece of software.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree about "method syntax" (is that what it's technically called?) ... I am completely OOP-minded, so I **think** in OOP, and the LINQ syntax ALWAYS slows me down!  Once in a while, however, it is less verbose and easier to read, so it does have its uses.

Comment: Yep, "query syntax" and "method syntax" are how Microsoft refers to them - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx. I find myself using query syntax when I have to do a lot of grouping.